# DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () error in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I upgraded my prestashop website from 1.6.0.13 to 1.6.1.23 . And it successfully upgraded. But i cant see my front end now . It always shows some error messages. But my backoffice is running smoothly.
error log is given below

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone ()' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\modules\ph_simpleblog\models\SimpleBlogHelper.php:19
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\modules\ph_simpleblog\models\SimpleBlogHelper.php(19):
>   DateTimeZone->__construct('') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\modules\ph_simpleblog\models\SimpleBlogPost.php(317):
>   SimpleBlogHelper::now(false) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\modules\ph_simpleblog\controllers\front\list.php(59):
>   SimpleBlogPost::getPosts(1, 5) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\classes\controller\Controller.php(189):
>   PH_SimpleBlogListModuleFrontController->initContent() #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\classes\Dispatcher.php(367):
>   ControllerCore->run() #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\index.php(28):
>   DispatcherCore->dispatch() #6 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\preproduction.bt.nl\modules\ph_simpleblog\models\SimpleBlogHelper.php
>   on line 19

Comment: This is because the value passed to `DateTimeZone` is either an invalid value, or possibly `null`. My first thought would be to check if a timezone is set. It might be worth googling how you check for this. [This might be a good starting point](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/prestashop-15/319-change-default-timezone)

Comment: Alternatively, did you update your server in any way when upgrading; e.g: update your version of PHP etc. If so, check what timezone is set in your PHP config (if any). You should be able to check `phpinfo()` or check on the terminal with `php -i | grep -i timezone`.

Comment: i didnt updated my php version

Comment: yes , the link you provided worked bro.. thanks